# godaddy shared hosting acme.sh

Tags: apache, ssl, shared-hosting

I am trying setup a free HTTPS on my godaddy shared hosting (its cPanel enabled) following the info on https://github.com/Neilpang/acme.sh from my mac.

However I am stuck...

What I have done so far:

1. Established an SSH connection to the server
2. Installed the acme as documented:

> ```
> git clone https://github.com/Neilpang/acme.sh.git
>
> cd ./acme.sh
>
> ./acme.sh --install
> ```

3.Closed the connection and reestablished (was required as indicated for getting the paths right or something)

4.Issues the certificate:

```
acme.sh --issue -d mydomain.com -w www --debug
```

I found that www is the directory in which my website resides...
After approx 10seconds the command says "Cert success"

5. Then I am lost...
   The acme website says "3. Install the issued cert to Apache/Nginx etc."
   with a command like:

> ```
> --apache--
> acme.sh --installcert -d example.com \
> --certpath      /path/to/certfile/in/apache/cert.pem  \
> --keypath       /path/to/keyfile/in/apache/key.pem  \
> --fullchainpath /path/to/fullchain/certfile/apache/fullchain.pem \
> --reloadcmd     "service apache2 restart"
> ```

```
or
```

> ```
> -nginx-
> acme.sh --installcert -d example.com \
> --keypath       /path/to/keyfile/in/nginx/key.pem  \
> --fullchainpath /path/to/fullchain/nginx/cert.pem \
> --reloadcmd     "service nginx restart"
> ```

I guess godaddy is using apache?
What are these /path/to/certfile/in/ directories? What are they for my godaddy installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using godaddy shared hosting, you can not restart/reload apache to enable the cert, since you are not root user.

So, you can not use `acme.sh --installcert ...` command.

Please copy the cert and key, and set the cert/key in you cpanel dashboard.

Thanks.

Comment: Confirmed, I copied the key and cert manually via the cpanel and all is working. I guess this also means I have to do this each 90d to avoid the cert expiering? Is there no possibility to automate this?